# finding a nonstandard arithmetic model containing an infinite prime number p

Tags: logic, prime-numbers

I'm just thinking about **the problem of finding a nonstandard arithmetic model like $\mathcal{M}$** (let's say an $\mathcal{L}_{NT}$ structure with $Th(\mathcal{M}) = Th(\mathbb{N})$ such that **$\mathcal{M}$ contains an infinite prime number $p$**).

My semantic interpretation of the argument by the structure is as following (I'm not sure they're sufficient!):

- $\forall v \in \mathbb{N}: v^{\mathcal{M}} <^{\mathcal{M}} p$ where $v^{\mathcal{M}}$ stands for applying successor function $n$ times to constant $0$, like: $S^{\mathcal{M}}(S^{\mathcal{M}}(...S^{\mathcal{M}}(0^{\mathcal{M}})..))$, meaning: "$p$ is infinite".
- "p is prime", by $p = .^{\mathcal{M}}(x,y)$, implying $x = 1^{\mathcal{M}}$ or $y = 1^{\mathcal{M}}$ $~~~~\forall x,y \in \mathcal{M}$. (Operator $<.>$ represents production.)

Any idea?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence "For every $n$, there is a prime number $p>n$" can be expressed in the language of arithmetic, and is true in $\mathbb{N}$; so is also true in any nonstandard model $\mathcal{M}$. Let $c\in\mathcal{M}$ be *any* infinite element (which exists since $\mathcal{M}$ is nonstandard); then any prime (in the sense of $\mathcal{M}$) $p>c$ is an (externally) infinite prime, and such a $p$ exists for the reason above.

More generally, we can show by the same logic:

> If $P$ is any *definable property* - primeness, squareness, perfectness, etc. - which holds of infinitely many natural numbers, then any nonstandard model $\mathcal{M}$ of $Th(\mathbb{N}$) contains infinite "natural numbers" $c$ with property $P$ (that is, such that $\mathcal{M}\models P(c)$; note that for this to make sense, $P$ has to be definable).

---

A commenter has asked for a more formal proof. Frankly, the argument in the first paragraph is perfectly rigorous, but here's another go:

The sentence $\varphi=$"$\forall x\exists y(y$ is prime and $x<y)$" is a sentence in the language of arithmetic (well, "is prime" isn't in the language of arithmetic, but we know how to express it in that language), and is true in the model $\mathbb{N}$, so is in $Th(\mathbb{N})$; since $\mathcal{M}\models Th(\mathbb{N})$, $\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$. Take an infinite element $c\in\mathcal{M}$; since $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$, there is a prime in $\mathcal{M}$ which is $>c$.

Comment: I didn't understand this part of the answer: `then any prime (in the sense of M) p>c is an (externally) infinite prime`. Could you elaborate a little bit on it? How do we know there are any p>c? It sounds to be the claim to be proved, not an assumption.

Comment: @A.Loc Because the statement "For all $x$, there is a prime $>x$" is in $Th(\mathbb{N})$, hence is true in $\mathcal{M}$. (Remember that $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all sentences true in $\mathbb{N}$ - well, the unboundedness of primes is certainly such a statement! So since $\mathcal{M}\models Th(\mathbb{N})$ .  . .)

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Maybe because your assertions are verbal, not mathematical. Could you formally present your proof?

Comment: @Roboticist See my edit. But *the proof in the first paragraph is entirely correct and rigorous already* - adding symbols doesn't make it more solid.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I think it's a deserving answer. Let's hope downvoters do so!

Comment: @NoahSchweber A question, if I may. How does such an infinite prime $p$ exist in a model with only one nonstandard element? (as constructed here, for example: 
[Elementary equivalence of standard and non-standard model of arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069333/elementary-equivalence-of-standard-and-non-standard-model-of-arithmetic)). We would then have $c = p$, and so $p < p$. Is this not a problem?

Comment: @sanguine There is no nonstandard model with only one nonstandard element. The linked construction describes (roughly) a model **generated by** a single nonstandard element, but there are always going to be lots of nonstandard elements if there is a single one: e.g. if $c$ is nonstandard consider $c+1$, or $c\cdot c$, or etc.