# Elementary equivalence of standard and non-standard model of arithmetic

Tags: model-theory, nonstandard-models

There is the common construction of a non-standard model of arithmetic by adding a constant symbol c to the signature and adding $\{n<c:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ to the theory PA. Now by adding all sentences $\sigma$ st. $\mathbb{N}\models \sigma$ we get a theory $T^*$, which is consistent by compactness theorem. My textbook says now that any model of $T^*$ is a model of PA which is elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$.

However, I found definitions of elementary equivalence only for models of the same language. The language of the model constructed above differs from the standard language $\mathcal{L}_{PA}$ by c.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any model of $T^*$ can also be considered as a model of PA by just forgetting about $c$.  In other words, you consider it as a structure with only the arithmetic operations and not the constant $c$.

Comment: So elementary equivalence (and isomorphy) of models are always relative to a signature?

Comment: Yes, though the signature usually is not stated explicitly.

Comment: But then how does a statement like "these models are not isomorphic, as they do not have the same order-type" make sense when the non-standard model is considered without c? Can we talk about the order-type of a model when we "forget" about some important sentences that are important for the order?

Comment: Of course we can still talk about the order-type, since $<$ is still part of the signature.

Comment: @GottlobtFrege We don't forget the *element named by* $c$, it's still part of the reduct, we just forget the *special name for it* (= corresponding constant symbol "$c$"). So we're not losing any elements - the "weird shape" of the nonstandard model (that is, its ordertype, which is different from that of $\mathbb{N}$) is still there.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So for example in the theorem "there are uncountably many nonisomorphic countable models of PA, which are all elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{N}$"  we are also just looking at sentences in the language of the standard model? So these models could be elementary equivalent relative to $\mathcal{L}_{PA}$, but not elementary equivalent relative to another signature?

Comment: @GottlobtFrege Yes, it is common for two inequivalent structures to have equivalent reducts. This is an example: if we extend the signature of $(\mathbb N,+,\cdot,0,1)$ to include $c,$ and interpret $c$ as $27,$ then $\mathbb N$ is not e.e. to any of the models of $T^*,$ even though their reducts to $(+,\cdot,0,1)$ are. Also, take any two non-e.e. models of PA. Their reducts to $(+,0,1)$ will be elementarily equivalent (since Presburger arithmetic is complete and PA is an extension).